# Format a float to n decimal places and no trailing zeros

Tags: go, floating-point-conversion

I want to display a float with the entire integer part and up to two decimals for the fractional part, without trailing zeros.

http://play.golang.org/p/mAdQl6erWX:

```
// Desired output: 
// "1.9"
// "10.9"
// "100.9"

fmt.Println("2g:")
fmt.Println(fmt.Sprintf("%.2g", 1.900)) // outputs "1.9"
fmt.Println(fmt.Sprintf("%.2g", 10.900)) // outputs "11"
fmt.Println(fmt.Sprintf("%.2g", 100.900)) // outputs "1e+02"

fmt.Println("\n2f:")
fmt.Println(fmt.Sprintf("%.2f", 1.900)) // outputs "1.90"
fmt.Println(fmt.Sprintf("%.2f", 10.900)) // outputs "10.90"
fmt.Println(fmt.Sprintf("%.2f", 100.900)) // outputs "100.90"
```

Formatting with `2g` has the problem that it starts rounding when the integer increases order of magnitudes. Also, it sometimes displays numbers with an `e`.

Formatting with `2f` has the problem that it will display trailing zeros. I could write a post-processing function that removes trailing zeros, but I rather do this with `Sprintf`.

Can this be done in a generic way using `Sprintf`?
If not, what's a good way to do this?

Comment: In `%.Ng` N is a total number of digits, not a precision. Unfortunately I don't think you can implement your requirements using `Sprintf` only.

Answer (score 89, accepted):

`strconv.FormatFloat(10.900, 'f', -1, 64)`

This will result in `10.9`.

The `-1` as the third parameter tells the function to print the fewest digits necessary to accurately represent the float.

See here: https://golang.org/pkg/strconv/#FormatFloat

Comment: This does not strictly solve their problem, because they want a precision of 2 points.

Answer (score 7):

Not sure for `Sprintf` but to make it worked. Just trim right, first `0` then `.`.

```
fmt.Println(strings.TrimRight(strings.TrimRight(fmt.Sprintf("%.2f", 100.900), "0"), ".")) // 100.9
fmt.Println(strings.TrimRight(strings.TrimRight(fmt.Sprintf("%.2f", 100.0), "0"), ".")) // 100
```

Answer (score 6):

I used the below func to achive the same:

```golang
//return 45.00 with "45" or 45.50 with "45.5"
func betterFormat(num float32) string {
    s := fmt.Sprintf("%.4f", num)
    return strings.TrimRight(strings.TrimRight(s, "0"), ".")
}
```

Comment: @SergeyPonomarev that won't work. In case the number is `10.0`, it will become just `1`

Comment: @FirstOne you are right, I removed my comment to avoid confusion

Answer (score 2):

Use the below function to format and control the number of digits.

```
func FormatFloat(num float64, prc int) string {
    var (
        zero, dot = "0", "."

        str = fmt.Sprintf("%."+strconv.Itoa(prc)+"f", num)
    )
    
    return strings.TrimRight(strings.TrimRight(str, zero), dot)
}
```

Here is an example:

```
// Converts 18.24100100 to 18.24
fmt.Println(FormatFloat(18.24100100, 2))
```

Answer (score 0):

We must trim those zeros ourselves. We can use `TrimRight(priceStr, "0.")`, but I've written a faster trimmer:

```
func formatPrice(price float32) string {
    // truncate to 3 digits after point
    priceStr := strconv.FormatFloat(float64(price), 'f', 3, 32)
    priceStr = trimFloatTrailingZeros(priceStr)
    return priceStr
}

// trimFloatTrailingZeros the FormatFloat add padding zeros e.g. 20.900 to 20.9 or 10.0 to 10
// Note: the number must contain the decimal dot e.g. as result of format
func trimFloatTrailingZeros2(s []byte) []byte {
    i := len(s) - 1
    for ; i >= 1; i-- {
        digit := s[i]
        if digit == '0' {
        } else {
            if digit == '.' {
                return s[:i]
            } else {
                return s[:i+1]
            }
        }
    }
    return s
}
```